# Different output from WP-CLI in bash vs PHP exec()

Tags: php, wp-cli

I installed [this package](https://github.com/aaemnnosttv/wp-cli-login-command) on WP-CLI. When I run `wp login create` in **bash** it works fine, but when I run `exec("wp login create")` in PHP script **WP-CLI** return this error:

> Error: 'login' is not a registered wp command. See 'wp help' for available commands.
>
> Did you mean 'plugin'?

I checked the user from `exec("whoami")` and it's the same. How can I find the problem?

**EDIT**

when I run `wp package list` in PHP it returns:

> Error: Composer directory '/.wp-cli/packages' for packages couldn't be created: mkdir(): Permission denied

Comment: You might get different result because you are running the commands under different user.

Comment: but I run the command in bash with a user named **admin@server** and when I run `exec("whoami")` in PHP it says **admin**. can you explain how are they different?

Comment: is the group also the same?

Comment: yes it is the same. I checked with `hostname` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Alain Schlesser](https://wordpress.slack.com/team/U04F16G6L) in wordpress slack:

The folder that the packages are installed into is set to use your server user's home folder. When you try to execute this command from PHP, however, it is being executed by the webserver's user, which probably has a different home folder, and the package is not installed in there.

You can either load the package manually as part of the system (requiring it in the site's Composer stack, for example), or set the package folder to a location that is shared by both your user and your webserver (and reinstall it afterwards).

You can set the packages folder with the `WP_CLI_PACKAGES_DIR` environment variable: https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/config/#environment-variables